# reading and displaying large text files through C++

Tags: c++, text-files

im studiying basics of c++.
i want to display a .txt file of ANSI form through C++,but it only displays 25 lines;
what to do to display large text files like 100 lines long?

the code i use now is :

```
char c[15];
ifstream f("file.txt",ios::in);
f.seekg(0);
while(!f.eof())
{f>>c;
cout<<c;
}
getch();
f.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
std::string text;
while (std::getline(f, text))
{
  std::cout << text << std::endl;
}
```

Don't use character arrays, as they can overflow.

In your code, you are limited to 15 characters per read because of the size of the array.

The `f >> c` may overrun your array, as you haven't told the system how many characters to read.

See also [Why `eof` in a loop is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: I was with you right up until [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html)! (Also, `using namespace std;`?)

Comment: @BoBTFish:  I added the `std::` prefix.  The `endl` is to flush the buffer every line; a newbie thing.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I *don't* like teaching it to newbies. Too many newbies think it is the only "right" way to stream out a newline. When I see it in code, I can only ever assume it was used incorrectly. Like here. Do you *really* want to flush every line? And if so, be explicit about it (`std::flush`).

Answer (score 1):

Read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong?s=1|2.7856)

If you must use character array as buffer, then you should use the `std::istream::read` with its size. It's going to require more work to get that right.

You should probably prefer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::ifstream file("file.txt");
    for(std::string line; std::getline(file, line);)
        std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```